# Handle exception Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I have a doubt about handling DB exception in a Rails app.

In my app (an e-commerce) when I want to buy a product I click on "Add Product" and in my controller I find the product with that ID (that I pass by params) and save the product into a `line_items` table.

When i do `@product = Product.find(params[:id])` should I handle a possible exception? Is it possible to have a record not found or something else?
by default rails doesn't add any kind of error handling.

When i insert something in a table, the rails validation should handle my error. no? or better, the `.save` should protect me.

So, should I insert some kind of protection in these db operation? If yes, how can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails and Ruby provide you the necessary tools to raise, handle and manage the exceptions. But it's up to you to properly glue them together in order to build a solid application.

Rails and Ruby can't magically do all the job for the programmers. They can't understand in each case what you want to do. You need to write code in order to instruct your application how to behave.

For example, `Product.find` raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if the ID doesn't match any record in the database. But by default, this error is not rescued. It's up to you to rescue it using the macro and the feature provided to you by Ruby and Rails.

Generally speaking, you may want to rescue it and show a 404 error page. But if you scope `find` to get only the products associated with an user

```
Product.where(user_id: current_user.id).find(params[:id])
```

then the `RecordNotFound` may assume a different meaning. In this case, the record may exist but in another user profile, therefore you may want to render a 401 error page.

As you can see, Ruby and Rails can't make these decisions for the programmer because the correct error management is part of the decision you have to make in order to build your app.

Comment: `Product.find_by(id: params[:id])` will also return `nil` when nothing was found, and not raise an exception.

Comment: "But by default, this error is not rescued. It's up to you to rescue it using the macro and the feature provided to you by Ruby and Rails." Oh is it? [Doesn't it display plain 404 in production if that exception is raised?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue)

Comment: @D-side good to know, I must have missed the change. I'm quite sure it was not at the beginning.

Comment: @YuryLebedev I know about it, but mine was just an example of why Rails/Ruby can't magically rescue everything.